# How to have SBT subproject with multiple Scala versions?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13, cross-build

I have a project using Scala 2.10 and one using Scala 2.11. They depend on a common project, which can compile with both.

```
lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(baz).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(baz).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

lazy val baz = (project in file("baz")).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.4"),
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)
```

And then

```
$ sbt bar/update
[info] Updating {file:/home/paul/Private/test/}bar...
[info] Resolving baz#baz_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: baz#baz_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/paul/.ivy2/local/baz/baz_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/baz/baz_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/baz_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: baz#baz_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last bar/*:update for the full output.
[error] (bar/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: baz#baz_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 13, 2015 11:42:51 AM
```

How can I have `baz` usable by both projects?

Comment: Have you tried the `crossPaths := false` option, to ignore scala versions at all?

Comment: There is a chance that you'll have some comparability issues (not 100%), but to be honest your situation smells bad anyways; so I would suggest this as a temporary fix, until you make *foo* and *baz* use 2.11.4 both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created an [SBT plugin](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/sbt-cross) for this.

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

addSbtPlugin("com.lucidchart" % "sbt-cross" % "1.0")
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(baz_2_10).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(baz_2_11).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
)

lazy val baz = (project in file("baz")).cross

lazy val baz_2_10 = baz("2.10.4")

lazy val baz_2_11 = baz("2.11.5")
```

It takes a couple more lines, but now everything compiles as expected: `sbt foo/compile` works, and `sbt bar/compile` works.

You don't have to remember unique commands, you don't have bugs from `crossPath := false`, and unlike `++`, this is parallelizable: `sbt compile` will compile `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` with the correct Scala versions concurrently.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't play well with Intellij, but when ran from sbt - fast and awesome.

Comment: Works OK with IntellJ `2017.1.4`

Comment: @Tvaroh I think it works with Intellij as well or better than any other solution. File a bug on the Github project if you observe otherwise.

Comment: @PaulDraper it works only when all modules are set up for cross building. If a subset - it doesn't.

Comment: Does it play well with the workflow for publishing packages?

Answer (score 10):

Yevgeniy Mordovkin's proposed solution, to declare `crossPaths := false` in the baz project, works.

Another thing you might do, is to prepend a `+` before the command: `sbt '+ bar/update'`. That will build **baz** for all declared Scala versions.

Comment: Thanks. **(1)** Will `crossPaths` cause problems, as Scala minor versions are not binary compatible? **(2)** It seems for `+` to work, I also need to add `crossVersions` to `bar`, and switch projects with `project bar` and then `+update` (instead of `+bar/update`), otherwise it uses 2.10.

Comment: @PaulDraper no need to add `crossScalaVersions` to `bar`. What you have to do is set the `settings` before declaring `dependsOn`: `lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.4").dependsOn(baz)`.

Comment: @PaulDraper you can use `update` without a preceding `+` inside `bar` as long as you've already compiled `baz` for all declared versions.

Comment: @PaulDraper and yes, setting `crossPaths := false` might cause problems down the line, so you're better off not using it.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Unfortunately, putting `settings` before `aggregate` in the same way doesn't seem to work. Is it expected to? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231293/cross-compiling-aggregate-projects-with-different-crossscalaversions-for-subproj and https://github.com/scalan/scalan-ce/tree/include-lms-backend-in-root

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar setup, and got it work like so:

```
lazy val baz = (project in file("baz")).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.4")
)
lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(baz).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)
lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(baz).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)
```

And building with

```
sbt '++ 2.10.4 baz/compile' 'bar/compile' '++ 2.11.4 baz/compile' 'foo/compile'
```