# SBT Scala cross versions, with aggregation and dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.13, cross-build

I am struggling with how `crossScalaVersions` works with subprojects.

I have a project that compiles with 2.10 (foo) and a project that compiles with 2.11 (bar). They share a cross compiled project (common).

How can I compile projects foo and bar?

---

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(foo, bar).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.4")
)

lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(common).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4"),
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(common).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.4"),
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

lazy val common = (project in file("common")).settings(
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.4", "2.11.4")
)
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

**foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala**

```
object Foo {
  <xml>{new C}</xml>
}
```

**bar/src/main/scala/Bar.scala**

```
case class Bar(a: C, b: C, c: C, d: C, e: C, f: C, g: C,
  h: C, i: C, j: C, k: C, l: C, m: C, n: C, o: C, p: C,
  q: C, r: C, s: C, t: C, u: C, v: C, w: C, x: C, y: C,
  z: C)
```

**common/src/main/scala/Common.scala**

```
class C {}
```

---

**Attempt 1**

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: common#common_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      common:common_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]        +- bar:bar_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: common#common_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

**Attempt 2**

```
$ sbt +compile
[error] /home/paul/test/bar/src/main/scala/Bar.scala:1: Implementation restriction: case classes cannot have more than 22 parameters.
[error] case class Bar(a: C, b: C, c: C, d: C, e: C, f: C, g: C,
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (bar/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

**Attempt 3**

```
$ sbt foo/compile bar/compile
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: common#common_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      common:common_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn]        +- bar:bar_2.11:0.1-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: common#common_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

**Attempt 4**

```
$ sbt +foo/compile +bar/compile
[error] /home/paul/test3/foo/src/main/scala/Foo.scala:2: To compile XML syntax, the scala.xml package must be on the classpath.
[error] Please see http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html#scala-xml.
[error]   <xml>{new C}</xml>
[error]   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (foo/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

**Attempt 5**

I even tried defining `common_2_10` and `common_2_11` projects with that same base directory but different scala versions. I recall reading that targets are namespaced by Scala version, but SBT says there is a conflict.

```
$ sbt
[error] Overlapping output directories:/home/paul/test3/common/target:
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/paul/test3/,common_2_10)
[error]     ProjectRef(file:/home/paul/test3/,common_2_11)
```

---

The only thing I've gotten to work is manually specifying versions:

```
$ sbt ++2.10.4 foo/compile ++2.11.4 bar/compile
```

But this is a lot of commands, can never use parallelism, and obviates the whole use of (1) project aggregation and (2) cross building.

Am I missing something fundamental about the intent of `crossScalaVersions`? Or is there a way to have it play well with the rest of SBT, and for me to compile my heterogeneous projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wound up declaring common twice, once for each version.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).aggregate(foo, bar)

lazy val foo = (project in file("foo")).dependsOn(common_2_10).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val bar = (project in file("bar")).dependsOn(common_2_11).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)

def commonProject = (project in file("common")).settings(
  target := baseDirectory.value / s"target-${scalaVersion.value}"
)

lazy val common_2_10 = commonProject.settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val common_2_11 = commonProject.settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)
```

Note that I had to make the target directories different, or else SBT would reject it because they overlapped.

Also note that `def` makes `commonProject` not included the SBT's magical (reflection-based) search for project definitions.

---

This isn't the prettiest, but it is robust, readable, and reasonable. All commands/tasks work as one might expect.

In one way this is *even better* than `crossScalaVersions`, in that 2.10 and 2.11 projects can now be compiled **in parallel**, which does not happen with `crossScalaVersions` :)

---

EDIT: I created an SBT plugin, [sbt-cross](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/sbt-cross), to help out with this.

Comment: Excellent plugin! So much more than `sbt-doge`! At least in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my [sbt-doge](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-doge):

> sbt plugin to aggregate tasks across subprojects and their crossScalaVersions

Comment: Hm. Nice. `$ sbt 'very compile'`. Thanks!